# Special characteristics for XSLT in ABAP/SAP?

Tags: xml, xslt, abap

I'm trying to parse an incoming XML file into a SAP structure using XSLT. I read many tutorials about it and tried many things to get it to work, but something doesn't quite fit.

My Input-XML (shortened example):

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<result>
<row>
<idSite>1</idSite>
<idVisit>5814001</idVisit>
<visitIp>62.225.0.0</visitIp>
<visitorId>8765462c24df752f</visitorId>
<actionDetails>
<row>
<type>action</type>
<url>
http://localhost/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/1401-B1-Site
</url>
<pageTitle>
XXX
</pageTitle>
<pageIdAction>6817739</pageIdAction>
<serverTimePretty>Feb 16, 2017 08:15:19</serverTimePretty>
<pageId>48157003</pageId>
<generationTime>41.13s</generationTime>
<timeSpent>972</timeSpent>
<timeSpentPretty>16 min 12s</timeSpentPretty>
<icon/>
<timestamp>1487232919</timestamp>
</row>
<row>
<type>search</type>
<url/>
<pageIdAction/>
<serverTimePretty>Feb 16, 2017 08:31:31</serverTimePretty>
<pageId>48176219</pageId>
<siteSearchKeyword>sc</siteSearchKeyword>
<generationTime>9.21s</generationTime>
<timeSpent>58</timeSpent>
<timeSpentPretty>58s</timeSpentPretty>
<icon>plugins/Morpheus/images/search_ico.png</icon>
<timestamp>1487233891</timestamp>
</row>
<row>
<type>search</type>
<url/>
<pageIdAction/>
<serverTimePretty>Feb 16, 2017 08:32:29</serverTimePretty>
<pageId>48177539</pageId>
<siteSearchKeyword>sc</siteSearchKeyword>
<generationTime>3.31s</generationTime>
<timeSpent>137</timeSpent>
<timeSpentPretty>2 min 17s</timeSpentPretty>
<icon>plugins/Morpheus/images/search_ico.png</icon>
<timestamp>1487233949</timestamp>
</row>
<row>
<type>search</type>
<url/>
<pageIdAction/>
<serverTimePretty>Feb 16, 2017 08:34:46</serverTimePretty>
<pageId>48180485</pageId>
<siteSearchKeyword>sc</siteSearchKeyword>
<generationTime>3.33s</generationTime>
<timeSpent>34</timeSpent>
<timeSpentPretty>34s</timeSpentPretty>
<icon>plugins/Morpheus/images/search_ico.png</icon>
<timestamp>1487234086</timestamp>
</row>
<row>
<type>action</type>
<url>
http://localhost/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/1401-B1-Site
</url>
<pageTitle>
YYY
</pageTitle>
<pageIdAction>6817739</pageIdAction>
<serverTimePretty>Feb 16, 2017 08:35:20</serverTimePretty>
<pageId>48181187</pageId>
<generationTime>37.19s</generationTime>
<timeSpent>10</timeSpent>
<timeSpentPretty>10s</timeSpentPretty>
<icon/>
<timestamp>1487234120</timestamp>
</row>
<row>
<type>search</type>
<url/>
<pageIdAction/>
<serverTimePretty>Feb 16, 2017 08:35:30</serverTimePretty>
<pageId>48181399</pageId>
<siteSearchKeyword>schlauch</siteSearchKeyword>
<generationTime>3.03s</generationTime>
<timeSpent>157</timeSpent>
<timeSpentPretty>2 min 37s</timeSpentPretty>
<icon>plugins/Morpheus/images/search_ico.png</icon>
<timestamp>1487234130</timestamp>
</row>
<row>
<type>search</type>
<url/>
<pageIdAction/>
<serverTimePretty>Feb 16, 2017 08:38:07</serverTimePretty>
<pageId>48184883</pageId>
<siteSearchKeyword>schlauch</siteSearchKeyword>
<generationTime>2.69s</generationTime>
<timeSpent>118</timeSpent>
<timeSpentPretty>1 min 58s</timeSpentPretty>
<icon>plugins/Morpheus/images/search_ico.png</icon>
<timestamp>1487234287</timestamp>
</row>
<row>
<type>search</type>
<url/>
<pageIdAction/>
<serverTimePretty>Feb 16, 2017 08:40:05</serverTimePretty>
<pageId>48187525</pageId>
<siteSearchKeyword>schlauch</siteSearchKeyword>
<generationTime>2.83s</generationTime>
<timeSpent>267</timeSpent>
<timeSpentPretty>4 min 27s</timeSpentPretty>
<icon>plugins/Morpheus/images/search_ico.png</icon>
<timestamp>1487234405</timestamp>
</row>
</actionDetails>
<goalConversions>2</goalConversions>
<siteCurrency>EUR</siteCurrency>
<siteCurrencySymbol>€</siteCurrencySymbol>
<serverDate>2017-02-16</serverDate>
<visitServerHour>8</visitServerHour>
<lastActionTimestamp>1487233709</lastActionTimestamp>
<lastActionDateTime>2017-02-16 08:28:29</lastActionDateTime>
<userId>600000|600001</userId>
<visitorType>returning</visitorType>
<visitorTypeIcon>plugins/Live/images/returningVisitor.gif</visitorTypeIcon>
<visitConverted>1</visitConverted>
<visitConvertedIcon>plugins/Morpheus/images/goal.png</visitConvertedIcon>
<visitCount>2</visitCount>
<firstActionTimestamp>1487229319</firstActionTimestamp>
<visitEcommerceStatus>abandonedCart</visitEcommerceStatus>
<visitEcommerceStatusIcon>plugins/Morpheus/images/ecommerceAbandonedCart.gif</visitEcommerceStatusIcon>
<daysSinceFirstVisit>1</daysSinceFirstVisit>
<daysSinceLastEcommerceOrder>0</daysSinceLastEcommerceOrder>
<visitDuration>4391</visitDuration>
<visitDurationPretty>1 hours 13 min</visitDurationPretty>
<searches>13</searches>
<actions>28</actions>
<referrerType>website</referrerType>
<referrerTypeName>Websites</referrerTypeName>
<referrerKeyword/>
<referrerKeywordPosition/>
<referrerSearchEngineUrl/>
<referrerSearchEngineIcon/>
<languageCode>de-de</languageCode>
<language>Language code de-de</language>
<deviceType>Desktop</deviceType>
<deviceTypeIcon>plugins/DevicesDetection/images/screens/normal.gif</deviceTypeIcon>
<deviceBrand>Unknown</deviceBrand>
<deviceModel/>
<operatingSystem>Windows 7</operatingSystem>
<operatingSystemName>Windows</operatingSystemName>
<operatingSystemIcon>plugins/DevicesDetection/images/os/WIN.gif</operatingSystemIcon>
<operatingSystemCode>WIN</operatingSystemCode>
<operatingSystemVersion>7</operatingSystemVersion>
<browserFamily>Blink</browserFamily>
<browserFamilyDescription>Blink (Chrome, Opera)</browserFamilyDescription>
<browser>Chrome 56.0</browser>
<browserName>Chrome</browserName>
<browserIcon>plugins/DevicesDetection/images/browsers/CH.gif</browserIcon>
<browserCode>CH</browserCode>
<browserVersion>56.0</browserVersion>
<events>0</events>
<continent>Europe</continent>
<continentCode>eur</continentCode>
<country>Germany</country>
<visitLocalTime>08:15:19</visitLocalTime>
<visitLocalHour>8</visitLocalHour>
<daysSinceLastVisit>0</daysSinceLastVisit>
<customVariables>
<row>
<customVariableName1>saleschannel</customVariableName1>
<customVariableValue1>SV</customVariableValue1>
</row>
<row>
<customVariableName2>xxx</customVariableName2>
<customVariableValue2>xxx</customVariableValue2>
</row>
<row>
<customVariableName3>marketsegment</customVariableName3>
<customVariableValue3>0018</customVariableValue3>
</row>
<row>
<customVariableName4>login</customVariableName4>
<customVariableValue4>standard</customVariableValue4>
</row>
</customVariables>
<resolution>1920x1095</resolution>
<plugins>pdf, flash</plugins>
<pluginsIcons>
<row>
<pluginIcon>plugins/DevicePlugins/images/plugins/pdf.gif</pluginIcon>
<pluginName>pdf</pluginName>
</row>
<row>
<pluginIcon>plugins/DevicePlugins/images/plugins/flash.gif</pluginIcon>
<pluginName>flash</pluginName>
</row>
</pluginsIcons>
<serverTimestamp>1487233709</serverTimestamp>
<serverTimePretty>09:28:29</serverTimePretty>
<serverDatePretty>Thursday, February 16, 2017</serverDatePretty>
<serverDatePrettyFirstAction>Thursday, February 16, 2017</serverDatePrettyFirstAction>
<serverTimePrettyFirstAction>08:15:19</serverTimePrettyFirstAction>
</row>
</result>
```

My XSLT (also shortened, but it shows the crashing part):

```
    <xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl">
      <xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
      <asx:abap xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml" version="1.0">
        <asx:values>
          <RESULT>
            <xsl:for-each select="result/row">
              <VISIT>
                <xsl:variable name="check1" select="name()"/>
                <SERVERDATE>            <xsl:value-of select="serverDate"/>           </SERVERDATE>
                <USERID>                <xsl:value-of select="userId"/>               </USERID>
                <VISITORTYPE>           <xsl:value-of select="visitorType"/>          </VISITORTYPE>
                <VISITECOMMERCESTATUS>  <xsl:value-of select="visitECommerceOrder"/>  </VISITECOMMERCESTATUS>
                <DAYSSINCEFIRSTVISIT>   <xsl:value-of select="daysSinceFirstVisit"/>  </DAYSSINCEFIRSTVISIT>
                <VISITDURATION>         <xsl:value-of select="visitDuration"/>        </VISITDURATION>
                <SEARCHES>              <xsl:value-of select="searches"/>             </SEARCHES>
                <ACTIONS>               <xsl:value-of select="actions"/>              </ACTIONS>
                <REFERRERTYPE>          <xsl:value-of select="referrerType"/>         </REFERRERTYPE>
                <REFERRERTYPENAME>      <xsl:value-of select="referrerTypeName"/>     </REFERRERTYPENAME>
                <REFERRERNAME>          <xsl:value-of select="referrerName"/>         </REFERRERNAME>
                <REFERRERKEYWORD>       <xsl:value-of select="referrerKeyword"/>      </REFERRERKEYWORD>
                <DEVICETYPE>            <xsl:value-of select="deviceType"/>           </DEVICETYPE>
                <xsl:for-each select="actionDetails/row">
                  <xsl:variable name="row" select="current()" />
                  <ACTIONDETAILS>
                    <TYPE>              <xsl:value-of select="$row/type"/>               </TYPE>
                    <URL>               <xsl:value-of select="$row/url"/>                </URL>
                    <GOALNAME>          <xsl:value-of select="$row/goalName"/>           </GOALNAME>
                    <GOALID>            <xsl:value-of select="$row/goalId"/>             </GOALID>
                    <SITESEARCHKEYWORD> <xsl:value-of select="$row/siteSearchKeyword"/>  </SITESEARCHKEYWORD>
                    <ITEMS>             <xsl:value-of select="$row/items"/>              </ITEMS>
                    <xsl:for-each select="itemDetails/row">
                      <ITEMDETAILS>
                        <ITEMSKU>       <xsl:value-of select="itemSKU"/></ITEMSKU>
                        <ITEMNAME>      <xsl:value-of select="itemName"/></ITEMNAME>
                        <ITEMCATEGORY>  <xsl:value-of select="itemCategory"/></ITEMCATEGORY>
                        <PRICE>         <xsl:value-of select="price"/></PRICE>
                        <QUANTITY>      <xsl:value-of select="quantity"/></QUANTITY>
                      </ITEMDETAILS>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </ACTIONDETAILS>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <CUSTOMVARIABLES>
                  <xsl:for-each select="customVariables/row">
                    <xsl:if test="contains(name(), '4' )">
                      <IDENTIFIER>          <xsl:text> 4 </xsl:text>                      </IDENTIFIER>
                      <CUSTOMVARIABLENAME>  <xsl:value-of select="customVariableName4"/>  </CUSTOMVARIABLENAME>
                      <CUSTOMVARIABLEVALUE> <xsl:value-of select="customVariableValue4"/> </CUSTOMVARIABLEVALUE>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </CUSTOMVARIABLES>
                <RESULT>  <xsl:value-of select="result"/> </RESULT>
                <MESSAGE> <xsl:value-of select="message"/> </MESSAGE>
              </VISIT>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </RESULT>
        </asx:values>
      </asx:abap>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:transform>
```

Also, in case it matters, my transformation call:

```
 CALL TRANSFORMATION zz_tf_xmlvisit
      SOURCE XML myXml
      RESULT result = myVisits.
```

Now the problem: Once the parser moves to the first element in the second for-each-loop (in this case at 'type'), it crashes and the debugger throws an CX_XSLT_FORMAT_ERROR. Without debugging it just says "Unexpected text for XML-ABAP transformation."

I highly assume that there is some SAP-specific problem with the XSLT parser I don't know about. If I validate my transformation with an online validator, it works just fine.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue here. Please double-check to verify that you didn't accidentally cut out the data or statement causing the issue.

Comment: @vwegert I added a bigger example and the whole code. I had to eliminate sensible data first.

Comment: In your edit, you apparently lost the first two lines of the XSLT. Since I do not have your target data structure, I can only double-check using the test facility in STRANS, and that appears to work. Maybe the target data structure is incompatible to the asXML you're generating?

Comment: I thought of that too, but it should be exactly the same as in the xslt.
Visit is the main structure, it contains a internal table of actionDetails, which itself contains an internal table of itemDetails.

Comment: Meet the number one cause of bugs: "developer thought that it should be exactly the same" :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
...
 <DEVICETYPE>            <xsl:value-of select="deviceType"/>           </DEVICETYPE>
            <ACTIONDETAILS>
            <xsl:for-each select="actionDetails/row">
<!--              <xsl:variable name="row" select="current()" />-->
              <ACTIONDETAIL>
                <TYPE>              <xsl:value-of select="type"/>               </TYPE>
                <URL>               <xsl:value-of select="url"/>                </URL>
                <GOALNAME>          <xsl:value-of select="goalName"/>           </GOALNAME>
                <GOALID>            <xsl:value-of select="goalId"/>             </GOALID>
                <SITESEARCHKEYWORD> <xsl:value-of select="siteSearchKeyword"/>  </SITESEARCHKEYWORD>
                <ITEMS>             <xsl:value-of select="items"/>              </ITEMS>
                <ITEMDETAILS>
                <xsl:for-each select="itemDetails/row">
                  <ITEMDETAIL>
                    <ITEMSKU>       <xsl:value-of select="itemSKU"/></ITEMSKU>
                    <ITEMNAME>      <xsl:value-of select="itemName"/></ITEMNAME>
                    <ITEMCATEGORY>  <xsl:value-of select="itemCategory"/></ITEMCATEGORY>
                    <PRICE>         <xsl:value-of select="price"/></PRICE>
                    <QUANTITY>      <xsl:value-of select="quantity"/></QUANTITY>
                  </ITEMDETAIL>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </ITEMDETAILS>
              </ACTIONDETAIL>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </ACTIONDETAILS>
...
```

My structure was indeed correct :P 
I forgot to add the parent node ACTIONDETAIL**S** for my collection of ACTIONDETAIL. Thats why it was in the wrong node after all...
I does not explain though why it worked correctly in the validator, but at least it's working now.
Thanks!

Comment: That explains it perfectly, and it is exactly what I suspected: You generated something that wasn't an asXML representation of the target structure. The validator does not know or care about the target structure.